# How to prevent UITableViewCell to use leading space in editing mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `tableView` and in editing mode I do  not want to use leading space, moreover I want to keep content use the full available width.

[image]

```
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

I set editing style like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    return .None
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewDelegate` has a method just for this purpose

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if editing is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indentationLevel` and `indentationWidth` properties of UITableViewCell.

You can also set them in Interface Builder